# Live streaming is 2 hours behind after migrating to Dash.js 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I've just migrated my app from Dash.js 2.9.2 to 3.0.0.

Everything is fine with non-linear streams but when I open a live stream, it plays 2 hours behind from now.

I guess these 2 hours match the timeshift capability of my stream.

I tried to dig up into the code with Chrome DevTools and the first thing I noticed when comparing v2.9.2 and 3.0.0 is that after the stream has initialized, on the first `PLAYBACK_TIME_UPDATED` event, `element.currentTime` (in VideoModel) is indeed 2 hours behind.

Does v3.0.0 require something special when initializing a live stream?

I tried to seek to "now" but to no avail.

Comment: https://teambragi.bragi.com/t/how-reset-current-time-on-dash-its-off-by-2h/243

Comment: Thanks but I'm talking about the video player Dash.js: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki

Comment: sorry my bad. did maybe something with timezones change in version 3? i had a similar problem with a different framework. the issue was i didn't set the timezone correctly and then it just switched to UTC which, here i'm from, is 2 hours off

Comment: [here](http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html) are multiple functions that make use of UTC. Since i have no experience with Dash.js i can't really help but maybe there's some connection with UTC/Locales/Time Zones

Comment: My first thought was also about timezone since I'm in France, which is UTC+2 (at the moment). But I'm also playing live streams with a 2-hour timeshift buffer, so it could be either of them. Or something totally different, for that matter. But I'll give a look at the timezone lead. Thanks!